# Android val cannot be reassigned

Tags: android, kotlin

I defined a variable called notes, when i try to modify it from a method, android studio says

> val cannot be reassigned

however i can modify it if i access the variable like this: `this.notes`.

```
class NoteAdapter(var context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteViewHolder>(){

private var notes = emptyList<Note>()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false)
    return NoteViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return notes.size
}

fun setNotes(notes: List<Note>) {
    this.notes = notes
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Why is this happening?

I come from a Javascript background so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: you can not assign a value to `final` variable. `val` means `final` keyword in kotlin

Comment: Communicate indicates that you have used `val` keyword instead `var`.

Comment: let me guess: How you are trying to use it without `this` keyword? :`notes = notes`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You named two things `notes`:

```
private var notes = emptyList<Note>()
```

and:

```
fun setNotes(notes: List<Note>)
```

So, in the `setNotes()` function, `notes` refers to the function parameter. That is treated as a `val` and cannot be reassigned. `this.notes` refers to the `notes` property defined on your `NoteAdapter` class.

In general, try to use different names, to reduce confusion. For example, you might use:

```
fun setNotes(replacementNotes: List<Note>)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin,

**val** - When you declared any variable in Koltin as **final variable** so once assigned we cannot changes the value of it.

So use **var** when you need to define/change value while running application