# Val cannot be reassigned in android buildTool 30.0.1

Tags: android, kotlin

I am not familiar with kotlin. I have one app which was have build tool version 29.0.3 and below code was working fine.

```
init {
    // Make sure that the view finder reference is valid
    val viewFinder = viewFinderRef.get()
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid reference to view finder used")

    // Initialize the display and rotation from texture view information
    viewFinderRotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display)

    // Initialize public use-case with the given config
    previewUseCase = Preview(config)

    // Every time the view finder is updated, recompute layout
    previewUseCase.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener { output ->
        val vFinder = viewFinderRef.get() ?: return@setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener

        // To update the SurfaceTexture, we have to remove it and re-add it
        val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeView(viewFinder)
        parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

        // Update internal texture
        viewFinder.surfaceTexture = output.surfaceTexture
        bufferRotation = output.rotationDegrees
        val rotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display)
        updateTransform(vFinder, rotation, output.textureSize, viewFinderDimens)
    }

    // Every time the provided texture view changes, recompute layout
    viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, left, top, right, bottom, _, _, _, _ ->
        val vFinder = view as TextureView
        val newViewFinderDimens = Size(right - left, bottom - top)
        val rotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display)
        updateTransform(vFinder, rotation, bufferDimens, newViewFinderDimens)
    }
}
```

Today I am trying to update it to latest version 30.0.1 and its giving me error called `val cannot be reassigned` in line  `viewFinder.surfaceTexture = output.surfaceTexture`, There no any suggestion for it. I have tried to change val to var as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290337/android-val-cannot-be-reassigned), but its not solving that error, I dont know what I should change, Let me know if anyone can help me for same.
Thanks!

Comment: Would need to see your code for your `viewFinder` class to be able to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Android 30 SDK, [`setSurfaceTexture()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/TextureView#setsurfacetexture) has the appropriate `@NonNull` annotation (you can only set a non-null `SurfaceTexture`). However, [`getSurfaceTexture()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/TextureView#getsurfacetexture) returns a `SurfaceTexture?` (i.e., a nullable `SurfaceTexture`).

Kotlin does not support `var` property access when the types are different (and nullability is an important part of Kotlin typing) therefore Kotlin can only give you effectively the `val` equivalent when you call the `surfaceTexture` property.

This means that you need to explicitly use `setSurfaceTexture()` to set the `SurfaceTexture`:

```
viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(output.surfaceTexture)
```